# If statement is always false, WHY?

Tags: javascript, debugging, if-statement, logic

Nevermind the HTML and CSS, I've written my JS, and commented everything I possibly can to make it as easy to understand. Basically, it's a color guessing game and for some reason I can't work up the logic to work properly can anyone figure out the bug?

```
//Array of RGB colors for debuuging purpose
var colors = [
"RGB(255, 0, 0)",
"RGB(255, 255, 0)",
"RGB(255, 0, 255)",
"RGB(0, 255, 255)",
"RGB(0, 255, 0)",
"RGB(0, 0, 255)" ]

//Get all square class divs and put inside "squares"
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

//pick a set color as the right color for debugging purpose
var pickedColor = colors[3];

//Mach HTML <span> tag 
//******************************************************
var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;
//******************************************************

//loop through all the squares and assign
//    a set color from "colors" array
for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
//Add initial colors to squares
squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

//Add click listeners to squares
squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
    //grab color of clicked square
    var clickedColor = this.style.background;

    //compare color to pickedColor
    if(clickedColor === pickedColor){
        this.style.background = white;
    } else {
        this.style.background = "#232323";
        //Bug: For some reason, if statment is never
        //true. I can't find the problem please help.
    }
})
}
```

Comment: console.log([clickedColor, pickedColor]), browser may parse and can transform it to another format, can strip whitespaces, or can be different object.

Comment: Check `this.style.backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the assignment `squares[i].style.background = colors[i];` you are assigning strings like `"RGB(255, 0, 0)"` to the style and the browser is normalizing the strings to strings like `"rgb(255, 0, 0)"`. If you just use `rgb` instead of `RGB` it is going to work.

Another problem is that you didn't define `white`.

Here is the code with the bugs fixed.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <style>
                .square {
                    width: 150px;
                    height: 150px;
                    float: left;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <div class="square"></div>
            <span id="colorDisplay"></span>
            <script>
                var white = "RGB(255, 255, 255)"; // Adding white var.

                var colors = [
                    "RGB(255, 0, 0)",
                    "RGB(255, 255, 0)",
                    "RGB(255, 0, 255)",
                    "RGB(0, 255, 255)",
                    "RGB(0, 255, 0)",
                    "RGB(0, 0, 255)"
                ];

                var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");
                var pickedColor = colors[3];
                var colorDisplay = document.getElementById("colorDisplay");

                colorDisplay.textContent = pickedColor;

                for(var i = 0; i < squares.length; i++) {
                    squares[i].style.background = colors[i];

                    squares[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
                        var clickedColor = this.style.background;

                        // Using lower case
                        if(clickedColor === pickedColor.toLowerCase()){
                            this.style.background = white;
                        } else {
                            this.style.background = "#232323";
                        }
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.style.background` contain differents info like color,image, repeat, etc.

`pickedColor` is a string with just "RGB(x,y,z)".

The  right question is: why should they be the same?

[Here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp) more about this.style.background

**EDIT:**

Checking in practice your `RGB` is converted to `rgb`

Comment: this.style.background refers to squares[i] which refers to colors[i]

when I click on colors[i] in this case

Comment: @DaniRashba have you tried to print into the console?

Comment: @DaniRashba I checked, it convert to "rgb(100, 100, 100)", in lower case.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!!

for some reason, I was supposed to write rgb instead of RGB, and that led to another bug which I figured out quickly, I wrote white as a variable, instead of "white" as a string.